# Grub rescue mode always boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

i have a problem, my pc in every boot puts in mode grub rescue, i know the sequence for boot

```
set prefix=(hd1,msdos5)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

And after that the system boots normal (i have dual system, with dual hard drive, windows and Ubuntu 17.10, windows C lives in a ssd, sdb unit, and linux and a windows drive d lives in a normal hard drive sda), but i'm tired of make that

that happens after i reinstall the system (because i break the gui dependences), i try all solutions:

```
   update-grub
   grub-install
```

set manually:

```
   sudo grub-install --root-directory /mnt/sda5 /dev/sda
```

Anyone know some solution, for now my only choice is change from grub to lilo (but i don't get enought examples for make that process), is a normal boot (not uefi).

Answer (score 0):

`--root-directory /mnt/sda5` looks like it may be the problem. When you're installing grub, make sure your actual system's root is at `/` (chrooting if necessary to make this the case), then run `grub-install` without this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To recover grub:

1. Open the live version (boot from live dvd/usb)
2. Open the terminal and run sudo fdisk -l to see where Linux is installed.
3. Run sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt where x is the number you have found Linux word in
4. Run sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda to install grub.
5. Run sudo update-grub to update grub and if this command didn't work run it after rebooting.
6. Reboot.

Please change hdd name as per yours. Hope this helps. Excuse for the raw text as writing on phone.